# Python: Delete a special file

Tags: .htaccess, python-2.7

you know special files or folders where the first place is a point. For example: .example_folder or .examaple_file. Think about the .htaccess/.htpassword files. I know how to delete folders and files on the regular way with Python. But how can I delete some special files like this? The other problem is the special files don't have extensions like .txt oder .jpg etc.. When I try to delete the special files/folders on the regular way Python skips all the special files/folder. Does someone has any idea?

```
def delete_temp_update_files(path_files):

    files = glob.glob(path_files)
    for f in files:
            os.remove(f)

def delete_temp_update_folders(folder_path, path_files):

    folder_paths = glob.glob(folder_path)

    '''
    First, all folders are deleted in this current folder (folder_paths).
    '''
    if not folder_paths:
        '''
        The list (folder_paths) is empty, that means there aren't somer folders.
        In this case its enough to delete all files - everything including
        hidden files.
        '''
        result_files = delete_temp_update_files(path_files)
        return result_files
    else:
        '''
        There are some folders. Before the files are deleted, the folder must be deleted.
        '''
        for folder_element in folder_paths:
            shutil.rmtree(folder_element, ignore_errors=True)

        '''
        Now all folders are delete have been deleted. Netx all files should be deleted.
        '''
        result_files = delete_temp_update_files(path_files)
        return result_files

def on_delete_files_folders(update_temp_zip_file):
    # The variable named (all_files) shows all files - everything including hidden files
    all_files = os.path.join(update_temp_zip_file, '*')

    # The variable named (all_folders) shows all folders in current folder.
    all_folders = os.path.join(update_temp_zip_file, '*/')

    delete_temp_update_folders(all_folders, all_files)

on_delete_files_folders("PATH/TO/YOUR/FOLDER")
```

Comment: Can you show your deletion script? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Your decision is rather sophisticated.
You may use my script below:

```
import os

def del_recursive(path):
  for file in os.listdir(path):
    file = os.path.join(path, file)
    if os.path.isdir(file):
      try:
        os.rmdir(file)
      except:
        del_recursive(file)
        os.rmdir(file)
    else:
      os.remove(file)
```

If you want to delete everything in a directory you also may use `shutil.rmtree()`. Both variants work on Python 2.7.3.

Comment: My decision is rather sophisticated? Why? Back to your code. This script deletes the the destination folder. For example, when I write `del_recursive('D:\Dan\Python\Tutorials\del_folder')` it will deletes the folder del_folder, & not only the contents of the folder del_folder. In my case, the snippet works, but I can't delete special file/folder. In my folder, I have two special folders: .git & .idea & a special file named .htaccess. My script skips the special files & folders. That means: All files and folders were deleted in current folder, except for the specific files & folders.

Comment: Your decision is rather sophisticated, because you import excess packages and create a lot of functions. Use suitable packages for your tasks. For this one `import os` is enogh. My script deletes inner files recursively. By the way I edited it, so it doesn't delete destination folder.